# how to use the absolute path in the msbuild config file(*.proj)？

Tags: msbuild, appcmd

the relative content in msbuild.proj file:

```
<Message Text="*****check the site exists*****" Importance="high"/>
<Exec Command="C:\WINDOWS\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list site /name:$(WebAppSiteName) " ContinueOnError="true">
  <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode2" />
</Exec>

<Message Text="*****if not exists create site*****" Importance="high"  Condition="'$(ErrorCode2)' > '0'" />
<Exec Command="C:\WINDOWS\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe add site /name:$(WebAppSiteName) /bindings:http/*:80:$(SiteDomain) /applicationDefaults.applicationPool:$(WebAppSiteName) /physicalPath:$(BuildSolutionDir)$(DeployDir)Website" Condition="$(WebAppSiteName)!=''  and '$(ErrorCode2)' > '0'"></Exec>
```

in above: the actual parameter(/physicalPath） value of runtime is :
**D:\YDJWebsite.Dev\deply\fw\..\..\mkltest2Website**

actually, the path of above is equivalent to **D:\YDJWebsite.Dev\mkltest2Website**

when accessing the site, the error shows: 
500 - internal server error,
resource not found

if i change the path to right format "**D:\YDJWebsite.Dev\mkltest2Website**", the error disappeared

[the physical path of website in iis shows here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GBQg.png)

now, i know the only solution is to convert the paramter value(/physicalPath） to right format?

but how to do it in proj file? is there any suggestion ? tks.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the problem with the msbuild's inline task.

```
<UsingTask TaskName="AbsolutePath" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">
  <ParameterGroup>
      <Path ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <FullPath ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" />  
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
      <Reference Include="System.Core" />
      <Using Namespace="System" />
      <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
      <Using Namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
      <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build.Framework" />
      <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build.Utilities" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
          <![CDATA[
          try {
                if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Path))
                {
                    FullPath = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path);
                    FullPath = dirInfo.FullName;
                }
          }
          catch (Exception ex) {
            FullPath = "";
          }
      ]]>
      </Code>
  </Task>
```

```
<AbsolutePath Path="$(BuildSolutionDir)$(DeployDir)Website">
        <Output TaskParameter="FullPath" PropertyName="FullPath" />
    </AbsolutePath>
<Message Text="$(FullPath)"/>
```

tks.